# How to access localstorage from a popup window spawned by an iframe

Tags: javascript, local-storage

On a webpage belonging to the origin X, I have an iFrame belonging to the origin Y. In the iFrame is a button that opens a popup window which navigates to a webpage belonging to domain Y. When the iFrame page loads, it sets a localstorage key "abc". However, I do not have access to the localstorage of the iFrame from the popup. Is there any particular security policy reason for this to happen?

Example code:

iFrame.htm:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script>
        const setKey = ()=>{
            localStorage.setItem("abc","Good day")
        }
        const openPopup = ()=>{
            window.open("popup.htm","_blank","popup,left=100,top=100,width=320,height=600")
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="setKey()">
    <h1> iFrame </h1>
    <button onclick="openPopup()"> Open popup </button>
</body>
</html>
```

Popup.htm:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script>
        const accessStorage = ()=>{
            const abc = localStorage.getItem("abc")
            console.log(abc) //Null
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="accessStorage()">
    <h1> Popup</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Surprisingly, this works perfectly if I open iframe.htm in a new browser window instead of embedding it in my webpage belonging to domain X.

Comment: See Matt's answer: [domains are segregated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API#responding_to_storage_changes_with_the_storageevent). Specifically the notes about changes being ignored on the same page, and not being accessible for other domains

Comment: I tried your code on my local machine it is working fine. Can you please send more clue

Comment: @EphellonGrey thank you for the comment. I'm fine with changes being ignored on the same page. My popup is an entirely different page belonging to the same domain as the iframe, and as such, should ideally be notified about the change. The example I've shared in the question doesn't rely on localstorage events. The localstorage key is set by the iframe on page load, so later sometime when a user opens a popup, the popup should ideally be able to see the localstorage key set by the iframe.

Comment: @Ashish, thanks for the comment. Did you embed iframe.htm on another page before trying my example?

Answer (score 1):

From what I've tried and done, this doesn't seem possible. It's as if the browsers containerize the iframe's data, and do not allow access of it from other pages even though they're from the same origin. You might be out of luck.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Matt. Do you have an article or a document about this? I couldn't find any explanation about why this seems to happen

Comment: @JasonBourne I'm afraid neither do I. This is answer is simply my observation.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the localstorage of X when the iframe is of origin Y, but what you can do is use window.postMessage() to send a message from the iframe to X, setting up a message event listener on X, and then saving to localstorage from X.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage